# Cannot bring WFS layers from GeoServer to OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

So I found this course on Udemy and I made it to the part where we start adding vector layers into an OpenLayers map. However, the layer we add does not appear on my map! The code for this is here:

```
wfs_url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/richland_postgres/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0' +
          '&request=GetFeature' +
          '&typename=richland_postgres:schools&' +
          '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
          ',EPSG:3857';
        prompt('',wfs_url);

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/richland_postgres/wfs?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0' +
          '&request=GetFeature' +
          '&typename=richland_postgres:schools&' +
          '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
          'outputFormat=application/json' +
          '&srsname=EPSG:3857&,EPSG:3857';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  });

  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
  });
```

I copied and pasted the URL from the prompt into GeoServer and it gave me this: [image]

I think that is a GeoServer issue and I am about to have it re-installed anyway. However, I took out the CQL from my code and while the URL worked perfectly, however the layer still doesn't show up.

Looking around this site I did find another student from this class who had the same problem and someone suggested adding a BBOX. I tried that myself and it didn't work. I don't know whether it worked for them. I've tried a variety of tutorials but I have never been able to get a WFS into OpenLayers, however I can get it into QGIS. I wonder if this is a GeoServer issue.

Comment: What happens when you load the URL without the CQL filter in your browser? Additionally, have you checked the output of your WFS in Geoserver's OpenLayers previewer?

Comment: When I load the URL without the CQL filter it gives me the JSON. And yes, I have checked the output and it gives me the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a GeoServer issue!

The error message is quite clear the function is not recognised. If you turn up logging in GeoServer and then look in the log file you will see exactly which function is wrong. I suspect it may be to do with the double quoting of the attribute name, or the name of the geometry is wrong.

WFS queries don't work when you [have a filter and a BBOX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671977/geoserver-wfs-error-bbox-and-cql-filter-both-specified-but-are-mutually-excl) so the issue may be related to using a BBOX Strategy.

Another issue with your URL is the SRS is set as `EPSG:3857&,EPSG:3857` when it should be just  `EPSG:3857`.

Comment: Okay, it turns out the stable release does not have the querylayer module installed, so I can't use those functions. I couldn't find out where I could download that. I may just get the maintenance version installed next week. As for the vector layer, it still doesn't show up even after I eliminate all queries from my code and change the BBOX strategy.

Comment: It is under cross layer filtering for stable http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.12.1/extensions/geoserver-2.12.1-querylayer-plugin.zip

Comment: Okay, but do you know why I don't see my vector layer? I see the WMS layer just fine!

Comment: is anything returned from the server? if yes, then your projections do not match. If no, then your request is broken.

Comment: Hmm. The vector layer now shows up in my map. Maybe I hadn't put localhost:8080/geoserver/www/map.html as my URL? I could've sworn that I had! In any case, the problem is solved!